# Boot Error 0xc000000e caused by secondary hhd, i dont know why

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

Hey so my computer is getting the error 0xc000000e when I try to boot on my ssd  boot drive. I googled the error and did all the possible solutuions there it suggested to no avail until I unpluged my secondary storage hhd and then stopped getting the error. What could be the issue with my none boot drive that could be causing this issue?. I think it said something about winload.exe

Comment: Do not tell us you tried all of the solutions because if you had the problem would be fixed, and because you did we don't know what else to suggest. Instead, list each of the things you've tried and their outcomes, this will allow us to suggest alternatives that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the CPU Casing, eject both hard drives and check power and SATA cables. Then boot and press the key to enter to the BIOS firmware. Then go to the boot tab and set boot device 1 as your SSD. Save BIOS settings and reboot.

There can be also multiple primary hard disks causing the problem. I recommend you use one HDD for data storage, only as a logical drive and the SSD to install operating systems. You can backup all data of secondary HDD, convert it to logical and re-copy all data back.

Hope that helps